# Understanding __call__ with metaclasses

Tags: python, class, metaprogramming, metaclass

From my understanding the `__call__` method inside a class implements the function call operator, for example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I'm inside the __init__ method")

    def __call__(self):
        print("I'm inside the __call__ method")

x = Foo() #outputs "I'm inside the __init__ method"
x() #outputs "I'm inside the __call__ method"
```

However, I'm going through the [Python Cookbook](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393) and the writer defined a metaclass to control instance creation so that you can't instantiate an object directly. This is how he did it:

```
class NoInstance(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise TypeError("Can't instantaite class directly")


class Spam(metaclass=NoInstance):
    @staticmethod
    def grok(x):
        print("Spam.grok")

Spam.grok(42) #outputs "Spam.grok"

s = Spam() #outputs TypeError: Can't instantaite class directly
```

However, what I don't get is how `s()` wasn't called, yet it's `__call__` method was called.  How does this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Metaclasses implement how the class will behave (not the instance). So when you look at the instance creation:

```
x = Foo()
```

This literally "calls" the class `Foo`. That's why `__call__` of the metaclass is invoked before the `__new__` and `__init__` methods of your class initialize the instance.

---

As @Take_Care_ pointed out in the comments one great ressource on metaclasses is [ionelmc's blog post](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/) about "Understanding Python metaclasses". One image in that blog post directly applies to your situation:

[image]

The image is directly copied from the blog post.

Comment: great and simple answer ! .  If OP wants something more : https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i was looking for !

Comment: This makes it seem magical.  Also read Ignacio's simple answer below and read it again until this answer (and included diagram) no longer seems magical.   (After you do, you will realize that implementation of `type.__call__` *is* actually magical - it acts differently depending on its first argument / caller!)

Answer (score 3):

A class is simply an instance of its metaclass. Since the metaclass defines `__call__()`, calling the instance of the metaclass, i.e. the class, as a function, i.e. as a constructor, will invoke it.